# Ошибки SIGABRT и с sysmalloc

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы, malloc

Пишу программу по двоичным деревьям.

Для инициализации дерева я сделал отдельную процедуру, но при её вызове появляется очень странная ошибка.

В коде процедура зовётся initTree. Суть ошибки в том, что после того, как она отрабатывает, не может нормально выводиться текст в консоль, пишет ошибку (тоже в консоль):

```
Untitled^ malloc.c:2403: sysmalloc: Assertation '(old_top == initial_top (av) && 
old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inus (old_top) && 
((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed
```

Также если я запускаю отладчик, qtCreator рассказывает мне про ошибку SIGABRT

Я экспериментально выяснил, что если в начало этой процедуры добавить вывод любого текста, то сам этот текст не выводится, а в дальнейшем ошибка никак не проявляется и вывод вполне работает.

Я проверял это и с `<cstdio>`, и с `<iostream>`, результат был абсолютно одинаков.

Без этой самой процедуры ошибка тоже не появляется.

Вот код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

void preparationToCreateTree(int &n, int &posA);
void initTree(int &n, int &posA, int tree[], int numTree[], int &posZ);

int main()
{

    int posA = 1, posZ;
    int n;
    preparationToCreateTree(n, posA);
    int *numTree = new int[posA + n + 3 + 1];
    int *tree    = new int[n + 1];

    initTree(n, posA, tree, numTree, posZ);

    cout << "TESTED" << endl;   //Без строки ниже тут выкидывает ошибку
    return 0;
}


void preparationToCreateTree(int &n, int &posA)
{
    cin >> n;
    while(posA < n)
        posA *= 2;
}

void initTree(int &n, int &posA, int tree[], int numTree[] , int &posZ)
{
    cout << "Ahh.. Touch me, senpai!!";  //Без этой строки появляется ошибка
    tree[0] = -1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= posA + n + 3 + 1 - 1; i++)
        tree[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cin >> tree[i];

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        numTree[posA + i - 1] = i;

    if(n % 2 != 0)
        n++, tree[posA + n - 1] = 0;
    if((n / 2) % 2 != 0)
        n += 2, tree[posA + n - 1] = 0, tree[posA + n - 2] = 0;
    posZ = posA + n - 1;
}
```

Пишу на archlinux. Пользуюсь компиляторами gxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша программа имеет неопределенное поведение, так как имеется попытка обращения за пределы выделенной памяти для массивов.

В данном предложении

```
int *tree    = new int[n + 1];
```

выделена память для `n + 1` объектов типа `int`

Однако уже в этом цикле

```
for(int i = 1; i <= posA + n + 3 + 1 - 1; i++)
        tree[i] = 0;
```

идет обращение к элементам, индекс которых явно больше n в виду условия

```
i <= posA + n + 3 + 1 - 1
```

которое проще записать как

```
i <= posA + n + 3
```

К тому же внутри функции значение переменной `n` еще более увеличивается, а память для массива не перераспределяется

```
if(n % 2 != 0)
    n++, tree[posA + n - 1] = 0;
    ^^^^
if((n / 2) % 2 != 0)
    n += 2, tree[posA + n - 1] = 0, tree[posA + n - 2] = 0;
    ^^^^^^
```

Обратите внимание на стиль написания кода. Трудно понять, что ваша программа делает.

Старайтесь объявлять функции таким образом, чтобы они выполняли одно действие.  Например, в функции `preparationToCreateTree` ввод значения `n` следует перенести в другую функцию или в основной код `main`. В результате функция может быть упрощена и не использовать ссылки

```
int preparationToCreateTree( int n )
{
    int posA = 1;

    while( posA < n ) posA *= 2;

    return posA;
}
```

К тому же возникают вопросы, правильно ли вычисляется `posA`. Должно ли ее конечное значение быть меньше или равно `n`, или все же это ближайшее сверху значение.

Comment: posA вычисляется абсолютно правильно, зуб даю)) На счёт переменной n: А надо перераспределять память после этого? Я ведь изначально в массив выделил ячейки на 3 больше чем надо. Остаётся обнулить. Стиль и правда ужасный, я просто с этим не сильно заморачивался, т.к. задача сдаётся на сайт

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко Изначально вы выделили памяти  для n + 1 элементов: int *tree    = new int[n + 1];

Comment: А всё крылось в том, что я просто перепутал два массива. В том цикле надо менять numTree. После этого и фигня с выводом пропала))

Answer (score 1):

Ничего удивительного, у тебя идут ошибки памяти, потому что ты пишешь за пределы выделенной памяти. У тебя posA равно первой степени двойки БОЛЬШЕЙ n, а под tree выделено (n+1) элементов. Как ты думаешь, куда зайдёт цикл `for(int i = 1; i <= posA + n + 3 + 1 - 1; i++)` ?

Comment: Но откуда тогда ошибки с вводом-выводом? И почему одна строчка всё исправляет?

Comment: Ну вот такова природа ошибок с записью в невыделенные области - иногда их видно, иногда нет, зависит от очень многих условий (компоновка данных в памяти, и т.д.). Возможно что константа которую ты выводишь даёт дополнительный запас "не критичной" к повреждению памяти.
Точно сказать не могу, разумеется - это надо анализировать дизассемблированный код.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *tree    = new int[n + 1];
/* ... */
for(int i = 1; i <= posA + n + 3 + 1 - 1; i++)
    tree[i] = 0;
```

Сколько памяти выделено для `tree` и сколько данных в него пишется?

> И почему одна строчка всё исправляет?

Она ничего не исправляет. Когда запорота память программы может случиться что угодно. Другая строчка при выводе, другое действие, запуск программы из другого каталога, определённое системное время - всё это может замаскировать ошибку, а может и отформатировать винчестер, предварительно удалив все ваши аккаунты из соцсетей.

См. "[Неопределённое поведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)".

Comment: Иначе говоря, я криво работая с памятью получил ряд совпадений, из-за чего перестал работать нормально вывод?

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко, немного не так :) Нормальный код перестал работать из-за ошибок с памятью, а что после каких-то дополнительных действий ошибок стало не видно - это как раз случайное совпадение.

Comment: Теперь стало понятно, что тот костыль штука не совсем рабочая. Надо исправлять))

Answer (score 0):

> Я экспериментально выяснил, что если в начало этой процедуры добавить вывод любого текста, то сам этот текст не выводится, а в дальнейшем ошибка никак не проявляется и вывод вполне работает.

Как только вы сталкиваетесь с таким вот поведением - или когда изменения в одном месте вдруг влекут за собой изменение поведения совсем в другом месте, или когда программа под отладчиком работает, а без - нет - 95% (оценка неточная, может, и больше :)), что вы где-то портите память! Пишете за границами, удаляете неудаляемое или удаляете дважды, выделяете малый буфер - словом, перепроверяйте работу с памятью!

Comment: Я уже не первый раз проваливаюсь на работе с памятью. В принципе в этой задаче я мог и без динамики обойтись. Зато теперь я знаю как выглядит "Неопределённое поведение" :)

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко, а зачем вам тут про valgrind и аналоги рассказывали?

Comment: Я даже подумать не мог, что тут проблемы с работой с памятью

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко, а тут думать не надо :) Прогон программы через valgrind - просто часть процесса разработки. И если он ругнулся, то надо остановиться и искать ошибку, а не продолжать кодить.

Comment: Я думал, что в простых задачах на алгоритмы у меня не будет таких случаев, когда придётся трогать valgrind

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко, а "простые случаи" вы руками в машинные коды переводите, или тоже компилятор запускаете? Вот так и тут. Процесс сборки один для всех случаев. И да - даже матёрые гуру умудряются в программе из 3 строчек ошибок поналяпать :) Но они понимают, что вероятность такого события отлична от нуля, и не полагаются на "программа простая, что её проверять".

Comment: Ну,  теперь у меня на ПК есть несколько разных анализаторов. Буду пользоваться :) Лучше-бы просто избежал сложностей и взял не(!)динамический массив)